# Finding a Partition of a set and Quotient set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Lets take $A=\mathbb{NxN}$
and define the next realtions: $$(u_1,v_1)R(u_2,v_2)\iff |u_1-v_1|=|u_2-v_2| $$
I need to find the Partition of A and the Quotient set..
$$$$
so far i dont know what do they mean since theres are infinity partitions to it...
second, the quontient set is the group $\mathbb{N}$ (since it has all the numbers from 0 to infinity which are at N which means... all the group) am I corect?
thanks....

Comment: By $N$ do you mean $\mathbb{N}$, the set of all positive integers?

Comment: Indeed @shardulc just fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotient set is $\mathbb{N}$, because $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ the set of all pairs of positive integers whose difference is $n$ forms an equivalence class. For convenience, we can denote this class by $<n>$. The elements of $<n>$ are given by $(k, k\pm n)$ ($k - n$ has to be positive, else we do not consider it) for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thanks.. so its what I said...
but what about the Partition of A?
what is it and how can i find it?

Comment: I have described the partition by describing the equivalence classes. In what format do you want it?

Comment: i get it so you mean you define the partitions as $k,n \in \mathbb{N} (k,k+n)$

Comment: Yes, $(k, k+n)$ and when $k > n$, we have $(k, k-n)$ as well.

Comment: ok, but what is it a partition and not a Equivalence class? 
(Im not so good at this material and i dont understand so well..)

Comment: A partition of a set is a set of subsets such that the union of the subsets is the original set and the intersection of any two sets is the null set. Given a set and an equivalence relation on that set, an equivalence class is the set of all elements of the set which are equivalent. Given an equivalence relation, there is a corresponding unique partition and vice versa.